# Browse for sandbox files iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS sandbox. I am trying to list out all files within the device sandbox. I am not able to succeed it

My Code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"Files .. %@",[self showFiles]);
}


- (NSMutableArray *)showFiles
{
    NSError *err        = nil;
    NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&err];
    if(err) NSLog(@"showFiles() - ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    NSMutableArray *filePaths  = nil;

    int count = (int)[dirContent count];
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        [filePaths addObject:[dirContent objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return filePaths;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does it fail?  If you don't know then you need to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: with device sandbox you mean YOUR APP's own sandbox right? there is nothing shared. -- also you only list file in the sandbox's caches folder. Thats both ok?

Comment: Thanks for the approval @Daij-Djan

Comment: In console I am getting     Files .. (null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you are getting `nil` as you are passing back an unallocated array object:

```
NSMutableArray *filePaths  = nil;
```

You want:

```
NSMutableArray *filePaths  = [NSMutableArray new];
```

However given you are copying the filenames into this array from `dirContent`, you may just as well return `dirContent` directly:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)showFiles
{
    NSError *err        = nil;
    NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&err];
    if (!dirContent)
        NSLog(@"showFiles() - ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    return dirContent;
}
```

One further note: You are getting the contents of the *Caches* folder, which will be empty by default, as far as I know.

Comment: This is working perfect but displaying only the app folder contents